# How To Control Email Recipient With Form Dropdown?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am new to setting up forms. I have a form set up and sending to multiple people, but I now need it to send to multiple people that would be dependent on a dropdown list. I have searched around and can't get it to work. I am sure it is due to my lack of php knowledge. I would like the form to go to a couple of emails for each dealer they choose. So if they fill out the form, and choose "Dealer One" it would go to one set of emails and if they choose "Dealer Two" it would go to a different set of emails. Can some one help me out?

```
    <?php

// Set email variables


$email_to = 'ryan@example.com, ryan@example2.com, mike@example.com';


$email_subject = 'Request More Information';

// Set required fields
$required_fields = array('name','email');

// set error messages
$error_messages = array(
    'name' => 'Please enter a Name to proceed.',
    'email' => 'Please enter a valid Email Address to continue.',
);
// Where to redirect after form is processed. 
$url = 'http://www.example.com/confirmation.html'; 

// Set form status
$form_complete = FALSE;

// configure validation array
$validation = array();


//.....................................................................
//dropdown email list code:



//.....................................................................



// check form submittal
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    // Sanitise POST array
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = remove_email_injection(trim($value));

    // Loop into required fields and make sure they match our needs
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {       
        // the field has been submitted?
        if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

        // check there is information in the field?
        if($_POST[$field] == '') array_push($validation, $field);

        // validate the email address supplied
        if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email_address($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);
    }

    // basic validation result
    if(count($validation) == 0) {
        // Prepare our content string
        $email_content = 'New Website Comment: ' . "\n\n";

        // simple email content
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'submit') $email_content .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\n";
        }

        // if validation passed ok then send the email

        $email = explode(',', $email_to);

        foreach($email as $e) {
            $e = trim($e);
            mail($e, $email_subject, $email_content);
        }        

        // Update form switch
        $form_complete = TRUE;
    }
}

function validate_email_address($email = FALSE) {
    return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function remove_email_injection($field = FALSE) {
   return (str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:"), '', $field));
}
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
?>




<label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="name" id="name" name="name" size="25" maxlength="60" required autofocus placeholder="Name">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" size="25" maxlength="60" required placeholder="Email">
        <label for="address">Address:</label>
        <input type="address" id="address" name="address" size="25" maxlength="120" placeholder="Address">
        <label for="city">City:</label>
        <input type="city" id="city" name="city" size="25" maxlength="20" placeholder="City">
        <label for="tel">Telephone:</label>
        <input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" size="25" maxlength="18" placeholder="Telephone"> 

<!--surround the select box with a "custom-select" DIV element. Remember to set the width:-->
        <div class="custom-select" style="width:80%;">
        <label for="select">Select A Dealer</label>
        <select name="select_a_dealer" required="required" id="select_a_dealer" form="request_a_quote" >
            <option value="0">Select A Dealer</option>
            <option value="1">Dealer One - City One</option>
            <option value="2">Dealer Two - City Two</option>
            <option value="3">Dealer Three - City Three</option>

</div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="border-radius; .3rem; font-size:14px; padding:.5rem; margin:10px; width:30%; display:block">
        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" style="border-radius; .3rem; font-size:14px; padding:.5rem; margin:10px; width:30%; display:block">





    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct an array in your code that contains the addresses you want to use for dealer 1, dealer 2, etc then simply index into that array using the value selected by the `select_a_dealer` select on your form.

```
$dealersto = [
              1=>['joe@example.com','sam@example.com'],
              2=>['bob@example.com','sue@example.com']
             ];
```

In the code that sends the mail use the posted value of `select_a_dealer` as the key into the array to set the `to` address of the email.

Comment: Dave thank you for your response. Is there any way you can break this down a little for me? I am very new to this.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code that is sending the mail. Just need the bit around where the `to` address is set.

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you. I took some of what you gave me and some code I found. I appreciate your help.